# Rails form validation not working, no output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to get the validation working for my comment form assignment. For some reason all I get is my flash error being returned back to me. The way it is reacting (absolutely no output), I suspect I have not specified things properly.

> Comments will only need to be created for now, so generate a comments_controller with the appropriate action;
>
> Fill in the create action. It should create a new comment associated with a post and the current_user who created it;

```
flash[:error] = "Error saving the comment. Please try again."
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [topic, post, comment] do |f| %>
  <% if comment.errors.any? %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <h4>There are <%= pluralize(comment.errors.count, "error") %>.</h4>
      <ul>
        <% comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-inline">
    <%= form_group_tag(comment.errors[:body]) do %>
      <%= f.label :body %>
      <%= f.text_field :body, class: 'form-control'%>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Comment", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

in the form_group_tag I specified :body to match my label/text field.

here is my **Comment model** with :body and :user being specified

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

  # minimum 5 characters and must be signed in
  validates :body, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # find topic by id
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    # find post id through topic
    @post = @topic.posts.find(params[:post_id])
    # comments on post
    @comments = @post.comments

    @comment = current_user.comments.build(params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :post_id))
    @comment.post = @post
    
    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your comment was created."
      redirect_to [@topic, @post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error saving the comment. Please try again."
      redirect_to [@topic, @post]
    end
  end
end
```

If I press the submit button the flash error only appears, nothing related to the validation is returned back to me.

Comment: What do you have in def new?
Try @comment = current_user.comments.new instead of current_user.comments.build

Comment: It does the exact same thing. I will update the question, I am not supposed to have a 'def new' method.

Comment: As @bntzio and @mgrim mention, this is the root of your issue.  The usual paradigm is that the `new` action renders this form, which then posts to your `create` action.  So, if you want to re-render the form with additional (error) information, you would use `render 'new'`.  What controller action is rendering `_form.html.erb` initially?

Comment: It is a partial statement on my post#show view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **comments_controller.rb** you redirect on error, which reloads the page and resets the record. You should render the form view.

Try replacing the line

```
redirect_to [@topic, @post]
```

with

```
render :new
```

if `@comment.save` fails. (I assume you're following conventional naming.)

**EDIT:**

You'll might want to render the view that includes the "comments/_form" partial. I assumed it was "comments/new", but judging by your comments you might be looking for "posts/show". Render defaults to the current controller's views, but this can easily be overridden.

```
render "posts/show"
```

Comment: This throws me this error but I think I am understanding what you are getting at. "Missing template comments/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}."

Comment: Jonathan, you might want to create a template in app/views/comments/new.html.erb to resolve this error. This will theoretically throw the 'new' view or something like that.